# How to replay story (and optional) missions?

Tags: death-stranding

I am about 4/5 hours into the game and managed to get an S-rank on four missions. However, I have an A-ranked (story) mission that I would like to replay to get S-rank on. I could not figure out how to do it.

*Is it possible and if so how?*

Comment: Standard contracts will eventually repeat - you'll notice in the contract description the line saying something like "Previous score: A", for example. I don't think you can replay Sam-story-contracts

Comment: @Alien-47 Could you write this as an answer please?

Comment: Done. Last time I gave only a partial answer I got a downvote and people said it should be a comment)

Comment: @Alien-47 Urgh. Nothing like consistancy in SE sites, is there? I rather you posted an incomplete answer because it can be made better in time whereas comments are ephemeral. Any way, I will add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some special story missions (not your regular delivery orders) could be replayed from Private Room using Figures Stand: use "Examine Figures", then select "Nightmares and Memories" :

> [image: My stand with figures]

From there select specific episode, I have only episode 4 unlocked there so far:

> [image]

Comment: Would you mind expanding this please?

Comment: @Sardathrion-ReinstateMonica added screenshots and a bit more explanation!

Comment: That is great. /20char

Answer (score 3):

Standard contracts will eventually repeat - you'll notice in the contract description the line saying something like "Previous score: A", for example. I don't think you can replay Sam-story-contracts.

Comment: I specifically requested this comment to be made an answer. It's not like it cannot be expended once an official answer is found.